# Empty list message still shown despite circular progress bar implementation with LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, lazycolumn

I have a `LazyColumn` that displays a list of shopping list items retrieved from the database in the `ViewModel`. If the retrieved list of items is empty, the `LazyColumn` shows the following message: **"You don't have any items in this shopping list."** The problem is that this message displays briefly for 1 second before the items are displayed. To solve the problem I implemented a circular progress bar while the items are being retrieved, but it does not even appear, and the message is still displayed. How can I fix this?

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ShoppingListScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getAllShoppingListItemsUseCase: GetAllShoppingListItemsUseCase
) {
   private val _shoppingListItemsState = mutableStateOf<Flow<PagingData<ShoppingListItem>>?>(null)

   val shoppingListItemsState: State<Flow<PagingData<ShoppingListItem>>?> get() = _shoppingListItemsState

   val loading = mutableStateOf(false)

   init {
      loading.value = true
      getAllShoppingListItemsFromDb()
   }

   private fun getAllShoppingListItemsFromDb() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _shoppingListItemsState.value = getAllShoppingListItemsUseCase().distinctUntilChanged()
            loading.value = false
        }
    }
}
```

**ShoppingListScreen Composable**

```
fun ShoppingListScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    shoppingListScreenViewModel: ShoppingListScreenViewModel,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
    val allItems = shoppingListScreenViewModel.shoppingListItemsState.value?.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val showProgressBar = shoppingListScreenViewModel.loading.value

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CustomAppBar(
                title = "Shopping List Screen",
                titleFontSize = 20.sp,
                appBarElevation = 4.dp,
                navController = navController
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(SHOW_ADD_ITEM_DIALOG_STR, true)
                },
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                contentColor = Color.White
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "")
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        // Defaults to false
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = false,
        bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        Box {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(screenHeight)
                ) {
                    item {
                        if (allItems != null && allItems.itemCount == 0) {
                            Text("You don't have any items in this shopping list.")
                        }
                    }

                    items(
                        items = allItems!!,
                        key = { item ->
                            item.id
                        }
                    ) { item ->
                        ShoppingListScreenItem(
                            navController = navController,
                            item = item,
                            sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
                        ) { isChecked ->
                            scope.launch {
                                shoppingListScreenViewModel.changeItemChecked(item!!, isChecked)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(screenHeight - (screenHeight - 70.dp))) }
                }

            ConditionalCircularProgressBar(isDisplayed = showProgressBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
val showProgressBar = shoppingListScreenViewModel.loading.collectAsState() //Use collectAsState, with Flow state in the ViewModel
```

and add this condition to the "You don't have any items..." `if` like so:

```
if (allItems != null && allItems.itemCount == 0 && !showProgressBar) { ... }
```

The better solution would be to implement this with sealed class(es), where you would return different class for different state (e.g. Loading, Error, Empty, Data). And on the UI side, you just need to `when` over the possible types of data. [Here](https://betterprogramming.pub/managing-jetpack-compose-ui-state-with-sealed-classes-d864c1609279) you can find a perfect example.

Comment: The sealed class approach worked. Kudos for the link. Thanks.

Comment: How would I assign the `Empty` state in the `ViewModel`? How can I check if the `PagingData<ShoppingListItem>` is empty? I can't find an answer on SO or Google that works.

Comment: If you get zero entries from getAllShoppingListItemsUseCase(), then you set _shoppingListItemsState.value to <yourSealedClass>.Empty.

Comment: I understand you set the state to `<SealedClass>.Empty`, but how do I actually check to see if the `PagingData<ShoppingListItem>` is empty? I'm not sure how I would do it in the `ViewModel`.